# This has to be in the lit somewhere. Can someone point me to this in any accessible book or lit?

Tags: reference-request, summation, fourier-series, trigonometric-series, chebyshev-polynomials

It's just a big trig, sinusoidal, Fourier series thing:

$$\begin{align}
 y(t) &= \sum_{k=0}^{K} a_k \big( A \cos(\omega t) \big)^k \\
\\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^{K} b_n \cos(n \omega t) \\
\end{align}$$

The [result I got](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51759/harmonic-distortion-of-sine-signal-plotting-resulting-spectrum/51763#51763) (I think I fixed my error with the limits in swapping summations) is:

apparently, the DC component ($n=0$) of the Fourier cosine series is:

$$ b_0 =  a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K}{2} \right\rfloor} a_{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)^{2k}  $$

The coefficient for the even harmonic ($n$ even) terms:

$$ b_{n} = 2 \sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K}{2} \right\rfloor} a_{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{\left(k+\frac{n}{2}\right)! \left(k-\frac{n}{2}\right)!} \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)^{2k}  $$

And the coefficient for the odd harmonic ($n$ odd) terms:

$$ b_{n} = 2 \sum_{k=\frac{n-1}{2}}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K-1}{2} \right\rfloor} a_{2k+1} \frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+\frac{n+1}{2})!(k-\frac{n-1}{2})!} \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)^{2k+1}  $$

where $\lfloor u \rfloor$ is the `floor()` function, which is the largest integer no larger than the argument $u$.

$$ \lfloor u \rfloor \le u  < \lfloor u \rfloor + 1 \qquad \qquad \lfloor u \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}, u \in \mathbb{R}$$
or
$$  u-1 < \lfloor u \rfloor \le u  \qquad \qquad \lfloor u \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}, u \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: What, actually, is your question?

Comment: i want an expression for $b_n$, in terms of $K$, $A$, and all of the $a_k$ for $0 \le k \le K$.  this **has** to have been done before by someone.

Comment: we can set $A=1$ with no loss of generality.  but even with $A$ removed from the problem, i would still like to see a prior reference to this simple question and the non-so-simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP wants a reference, I would say the use the sums found in Prudnikov, Integrals and Series, vol. 1. 4.4.1.16 and 4.4.1.17. Ultimately they are not any more profound than the binomial theorem. In this particular situation they are, with a little algebra to clean them up

$$ \cos^{2n}(x)=2^{1-2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\cos{(2\,k\,x)} + 2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}$$
$$\cos^{2n+1}(x)=2^{-2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{n-k}\cos{((2\,k+1)x)} $$

The OP's procedure basically amounts to inserting these expressions in the original sum and interchanging the summations.

Comment: right.  but i was looking for a reference that also does that.

Comment: if i can get a reference that says
$$\sum_{k=0}^{K}a_k \big(\cos(\theta) \big)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{K} b_n \cos(n \theta)$$where$$\begin{align} b_0&=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K}{2} \right\rfloor}a_{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}(\tfrac12)^{2k}\\ \\ b_{2m}&=2\sum_{k=m}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K}{2} \right\rfloor}a_{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{\left(k+m\right)!\left(k-m\right)!} (\tfrac12)^{2k}\\ \\ b_{2m-1}&=2 \sum_{k=m-1}^{\left\lfloor \tfrac{K-1}{2} \right\rfloor}a_{2k+1}\frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+m)!(k-m+1)!} (\tfrac12)^{2k+1}\end{align}$$ 
where $m\in\mathbb{Z}\ge1$,
 that is the result i am looking for.

Comment: or, equivalently, if i can get a reference that says
$$\sum_{k=0}^{K}a_k \, x^k=\sum_{n=0}^{K} b_n T_n(x)$$ where $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th-order Tchebyshev polynomial of the first kind and the $b_n$ coefficients are as above, then i will feel that i found a prior reference.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a more relevant reference, but I would think a description of the technique is sufficient for most publications.

Comment: thank you skbmoore.  i dunno if/when i will ever write anything up.  but this is about a slight generalization (but not totally general) to the notion of *"waveshaping"* where a memoryless non-linearity is modeled as a finite-order polynomial, a sinusoid goes into the polynomial, and what comes out is a periodic function with an upper limit to the harmonics and we can compute the strength of each harmonic without doing the traditional Fourier series.  it's just seems to me to be a problem that someone else would have explicitly solved decades or longer ago.

Comment: if no one else weighs in with an answer, i think i'll give the bounty to you just because i hate waste.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Chebyshev polynomials $T_n$ are such that $T_n(\cos\theta) = \cos n\theta$; see [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) for details.  So you are given a polynomial $A(x)$ with known coefficients and want to find $b_k$ so that $A(x)=\sum_k b_k T_k(x)$.  A recipe is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions) where it says "with inverse $x^n = 2^{1-n}\sum\dots$".  Multiply both sides of that by your $a_n$ and sum;
the coefficient of $T_k(x)$ will be your desired $k$.

Added: A reference for the needed identity is Corollary 12 in [this paper](http://emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL15/Nkwanta/nkwanta2.pdf); I'm sure there are others.

Comment: i've known and understood Tchebyshev polynomials for 4 decades.  i know exactly why $T_n(\cos \theta) = cos(n \theta)$.  and this can get us to another result if the polynomial is, instead, framed as a sum of Tchebyshev's (like a different, but equivalent, set of basis functions).  Corrolary 12 looks like it might be useful (not complete) except that i cannot decode what "$T_0 \binom{2n}{n}$" means.

Comment: It means the polynomial $T_0$ times the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: $T_0(x)$ evaluated at what value of $x$?